# Need help updating dynamic dns on domains.google.com

Tags: vb.net, dns

I have some vb.net code I am trying to use to set the ip address of my new domain on donmains.google.com

The codes is below:

```
    Dim user As String = "MYRESOURSEID"
    Dim pwd As String = "MYRESOURCEPASSWORD"
    Dim host As String = "MYDOMAIN"

    Dim address As String = "https://" & user & ":" & pwd & "@domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=" & host

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(address)
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.Host = "domains.google.com"
    request.UserAgent = "Chrome/41.0"
    request.Headers.Add("From:mkhiliger@gmail.com")
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization:Basic base64-encoded-auth-string")
    request.ContentLength = 0

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

    Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

    reader.Close()
    response.Close()
```

if I paste the value of the address variable into a browser, it sets the domain fine, but when I 
use this code the responsefromserver is badauth.

Does anyone know what may be wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your credentials are not encoded for a start - the specs mention 'Note: Google Domains uses the dyndns2 protocol.' so I think you can re-work this DynDNS sub:

```
Private Sub DynUpdate(HostAddress As String, UserName As String, PassWord As String, MyWANIP As String, DynDNS_Agent As String)

    Dim MySocket As New TcpClient
    Dim MyStream As NetworkStream
    Dim MyUpdateURL() As Byte
    Dim MyReplyHTML As String
    Dim BytesRead As Integer
    Dim MyBuffer(4096) As Byte
    Dim Offset As Integer

    Dim ReturnCode, MoreInfo As String
    'Dim LastUpdate As Date

    Dim DynResultText As New Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary

    DynResultText.Add("badsys", "The system parameter given is not valid. Valid system parameters are dyndns, statdns and custom")
    DynResultText.Add("badagent", "The user agent that was sent has been blocked for not following specifications or no user agent was specified")
    DynResultText.Add("badauth", "The username or password specified are incorrect")
    DynResultText.Add("!donator", "An option available only to credited users (such as offline URL) was specified, but the user is not a credited user")

    Try
        ' Init and open the socket.
        MySocket.ReceiveTimeout = 20000
        MySocket.Connect("members.dyndns.org", 80)
        MyStream = MySocket.GetStream()
        ' Write the request.
        MyUpdateURL = ASCII.GetBytes("GET /nic/update?hostname=" & HostAddress & "&myip=" & MyWANIP & " HTTP/1.0" & vbCrLf & "Host: members.dyndns.org" & vbCrLf & "Authorization: Basic " & System.Convert.ToBase64String(ASCII.GetBytes(UserName & ":" & PassWord)) & vbCrLf & "User-Agent: " & DynDNS_Agent & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
        MyStream.Write(MyUpdateURL, 0, MyUpdateURL.Length)
        ' Read the respons.
        BytesRead = MyStream.Read(MyBuffer, 0, 4096)
        If BytesRead > 0 Then
            MyReplyHTML = ASCII.GetString(MyBuffer, 0, BytesRead)
            Offset = InStr(MyReplyHTML, vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
            If Offset > 0 And MyReplyHTML.Length > Offset + 4 Then
                ReturnCode = Split(Mid(MyReplyHTML, Offset + 4), " ")(0)

                Select Case LCase(ReturnCode)

                    Case "badsys", "badagent", "badauth", "notfqdn", "nohost", "numhost", "abuse"
                        ' "Server Update failed - Action Required")
                        If DynResultText.ContainsKey(ReturnCode) Then MoreInfo = DynResultText.Item(ReturnCode)
                        'should disable further updates

                    Case "good"    ' The update was successful, and the hostname is now updated.

                    Case "nochg"     ' The update was unnecessary, and the hostname is unchanged.

                    Case "dnserr", "911"
                        ' SeriousError
                    Case Else
                        ' "Server Update failed - Return code '" & ReturnCode & "'")
                End Select
            End If
        End If
        ' Clean up.
        MyStream = Nothing
        MySocket.Close()
        MySocket = Nothing

    Catch ex As Exception

        ' "Error Updating")
    End Try

End Sub
```